# What is wrong about my idea of this reference pointing to two different objects?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am new to C++ and I am struggling with the frequently found statement (e.g. in http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ref.html#fqa-8.1) that, in contrast to pointers, after initialization you cannot make a reference point to another object.

I have a code snippet here, which, in my opinion, does exactly that:

```
std::string s1("Hello");
std::string s2("World");
std::string& refToS = s1;  // initialize reference to object 1
cout << refToS << endl;
refToS = s2;               // make reference point to object 2
cout << refToS << endl;
```

The output is "Hello World".

This is probably a dull question but I cannot figure out what my misconception is.

Comment: Output `s1` and `s2` at each step, should give you a clue.

Comment: Ok I got it. The `refToS = s2;` statement actually replaces `s1` by `s2`, so not the reference is changed but the object it points to.

Comment: @Thomas789 that's correct understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is assign `s2` to `s1`, `refToS` is still refering to `s1`.

```
std::string s1("Hello");
std::string s2("World");
std::string& refToS = s1;  // initialize reference to object 1
cout << refToS << endl;
refToS = s2;               // assign s2 to the referent of refToS
cout << refToS << endl;    
cout << s1 << endl;
cout << s2 << endl;
```

Output is

```
Hello
World
World
World
```

Answer (score 0):

```
refToS = s2;  // make reference point to object 2
```

This line doesn't do what you think it does. On this like an assignment of `s2` to `s1` happens.

You can not change the object to which the reference points to.

Answer (score 0):

A reference *is* the object it references. So this code:

```
refToS = s2;
```

does not do what you think it does. It actually assigns the `s2` to what `refToS` references (which is `s1). So, this line actually does this:

```
s1 = s2;
```

And after it is executed, both `s2` and `s1` will be equal to "World"

Comment: It's actually still just a handle to a memory location.

Answer (score 0):

While John has correctly explained that you are actually calling `string::operator=(const string&)` on `s1`, changing `s1` not rebinding the reference, I thought it's important to point out that the FQA is mistaken here.

It IS possible to have the reference point to a different object, one that did not even exist when the reference was created.

The C++ Standard has the following rule:

> If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied, a pointer that
>   pointed to the original object, **a reference that referred to the original object**, or the name of the original object **will automatically refer to the new object** and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be
>   used to manipulate the new object, if:
>
> - the storage for the new object exactly overlays the storage location which the original object occupied,
>     and
> - the new object is of the same type as the original object (ignoring the top-level cv-qualifiers), and
> - the type of the original object is not const-qualified, and, if a class type, does not contain any non-static data member whose type is const-qualified or a reference type, and
> - the original object was a most derived object of type `T` and the new object is a most derived object of type `T` (that is, they are not base class subobjects).

In plain English, this means that a reference is bound to a particular memory location and cannot be rebound to another memory location.  But the object at that memory location can change (end lifetime of one, begin lifetime of another) so that the same reference can access multiple different objects.

To do this, use an explicit destructor call (ending the life of the object but but freeing the memory) and then placement-new:

```
refToS.~string();
// refToS now refers to raw storage
new (&refToS) std::string("Creating a new string");
```

This is not the same as using an assignment operator on `s1`, the result is an entirely new `std::string` object.

Clearly then, saying "the reference IS the object" is a misunderstanding.  Another proof that this statement is conceptually wrong is that when the object goes out of scope, a destructor runs.  When a reference goes out of scope, nothing happens.  A reference is a handle bound to a memory location during initialization (just like a `const` pointer), and being a handle, it is a distinct thing from the object itself.